# Many-to-one relationship: access in both models

Tags: django, django-models

I would like use the relation in both models, exemple:

```
from django.db import models

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    # ...
```

We can get car manufacturer like this:

```
car.manufacturer
```

But if i want manufacturer cars ? How can i modify my Manufacturer class ?

```
# exemple what i would like use
manufacturer.cars.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is almost correct. You don't need to change your class in any way - it's a feature built-in into Django. In reality your example should look like this:

```
manufacturer.car_set.all()
```

You can also similarly create new cars for a given manufacturer:

```
manufacturer.car_set.create(name='Fiat 126p')
```

You can find [full documentation of this feature in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: Thank's! I should miss it in doc :/